# Permalink not translating from function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

newbie to wordpress here.

I'm currently trying to add a fb share button to all images on my blog and have added this to functions.php:

```
    function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {

   // A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
   // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="facebook-share-btn fb-" data-fsb-service="facebook" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a></div>';

   // run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

   // return the processed content
   return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
```

Works well, except for the fact that the permalink isn't translating (It's sharing the php). There is something stupidly simple I know I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside single quotes strings are placed as it is, they are not converted... so you can use dot operator to concatenate the generated permalink... otherwise you need to escape the quotes... the following example uses string conctenation

```
   $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.get_permalink().'" class="facebook-share-btn fb-" data-fsb-service="facebook" data-href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are writing your PHP code into a string:

```
$replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . get_permalink() . '" class="facebook-share-btn fb-" data-fsb-service="facebook" data-href="' . get_permalink() . '"...
```

try that